# how to place Netbeans one Jlabel next another one

Tags: netbeans, jlabel

I want to place two buttons of my music player side by side, but in netbeans they won't, there is a small margin between them like on a screenshot. How to place them side by side?[image]

Comment: I have found it by myself, theres "edit layout space" context menu on item. you can change left margin to 0 there

Answer (score 0):

just use a layered panel to add the labels
or if your using netbeans 7.3(or higher) you could double click in between the two labels and a dialog box would appear and change the value to 0